# How do I get part of my code to loop and repeat a question until the answer is a valid input C++

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, do-while

The code works fine Im just missing the element where if the ending ask of repeating the game if I input "a" as a user I would want the code to repeat the question with a new cout statement such as " invalid answer please answer y/n and if yes obviously the game restarts itself
(ROCK paper scissors game b/w 2 players)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
char playAgain ='y' ;  // loop control


do
{
    char Player1;
    char Player2 = '\0';



    cout << "Player 1, Enter R, P, or S: ";         // Player 1
    cin >> Player1;

    Player1 = toupper(Player1);
    while (Player1 != 'R' && Player1 != 'P' && Player1 !='S' )
    {
        cout << "please only answer R , P , or S: " << endl;

        cin >> Player1;
        Player1 = toupper(Player1);


    }
    {
    cout << "Player 2, Enter R, P, or S: ";         // Player 2
    cin >> Player2;
     Player2 = toupper(Player2);
    while (Player2 != 'R' && Player2 != 'P' && Player2 !='S' )
    {

    cout << "please only answer R , P , or S: " << endl;

    cin >> Player2;
    Player2 = toupper(Player2);

    }}
    if (Player1 == Player2)     //TIE
    {
        cout << "Nobody wins."<<endl;}


 else   if (Player1 == 'R' && Player2 == 'P')
    {
        cout << "Paper covers rock, Player 2 wins."<< endl;
    }

   else if (Player1 == 'P' && Player2 == 'R')
    {
        cout << "Paper covers rock, Player 1 wins."<< endl;
    }
  else  if (Player1 == 'S' && Player2 == 'P')
    {
        cout << "Scissors cut paper, Player 1 wins."<< endl;
    }
  else  if (Player1 == 'P' && Player2 == 'S')
    {
        cout << "Scissors cut paper, Player 2 wins."<< endl;
    }
   else if (Player1 == 'R' && Player2 == 'S')
    {
        cout << "Rock breaks scissors, Player 1 wins."<< endl;
    }
   else if (Player1 == 'S' && Player2 == 'R')
    {
        cout << "Rock breaks scissors, Player 2 wins."<< endl;
    }

    {     cout << "Play again? (y/n): ";         // Player 1
    cin >> playAgain;
        if (playAgain=='N' || playAgain=='n')
        { cout <<"BYEEEEE"<<endl;}

    }}


while (playAgain=='Y' || playAgain=='y');

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just as a friendly suggestion, I would highly recommend keeping consistent indentation in your code, even if it's technically not required for it to run. It makes the code *much* easier to read, for yourself and for others. Once you start doing bigger projects you'll find it's much easier to change your code and understand what you wrote.

Comment: You perform input validation already for the R, P or S input. What would be different about validating the next input? By the way, another style suggestion is to name variables so that the name reflects their contents or purpose. `Player1` is a good name for a player (e.g. a struct holding a name and a score) but a bad name for input. (A better name could be `Player1Input`;-).) Another suggestion is to look up the do...while loop which can be used to avoid code duplication when an action (as e.g. user input) is *always* required and should be repeated until a condition is met.

Comment: Thank you so much im still in school for code hence the plebeian mistakes :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most elegant method is to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

static const std::set<std::string> RPS {
    "R",
    "P",
    "S"
};

static const std::set<std::string> yesno {
    "yes",
    "no"
};

std::string ask_user(
    const std::string& question,
    const std::set<std::string>& valid_answers
) {
    std::cout << question << std::flush; // outputs question (and flushes cout so it displays)
    std::string answer;
    while (true) { // this loop will terminate only when "break;" is reached
        std::getline(std::cin, answer); // get answer
        if (valid_answers.count(answer) == 0) { // if answer is not in valid_answers
            std::cout << "Invalid answer!" << std::endl; // complain to the user
        } else { // if answer is not invalid
            break; // exit loop
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Then you can ask for a move like this:

```
std::string p1_move = ask_user("Player 1 move (R/P/S)?\n", RPS);
```

or for a yes/no answer like this:

```
std::string answer = ask_user("Another game (yes/no)?\n", yesno);
```

This will prevent you from having to repeat code for both asking the user for a move, and for asking the user for another game, so it's better code practice.

Comment: That is a nice solution. One *could* construct the list of choices in the question from the set (with the maintainability benefit that when the set changes later, the question automatically updates with it), but perhaps that is overdesigned for this. Dunno.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
int main() {
    while(true) {
        char input;
        std::cout << "Would you like to continue the game? (y/n): ";
        std::cin >> input;

        if(input == 'n' || input == 'N')
            return 0;
        else if(input == 'y' || input == 'Y') {
            startGame();
            break;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Invalid response." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Play again? (y/n): ";
    cin >> playAgain;
while (playAgain != 'Y' && playAgain != 'y' && playAgain !='n' )
{     cout << "Error input :Play again? (y/n): ";         // Player 1
    cin >> playAgain;
```

^ Figured it out! Yeah went back to my indentation and compared to my first loop. Thanks so much all for helping :)